# How to make a content visible only in the corresponding language it has been created on a multilingual website

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I am buiding a website on **drupal 7** in french and english.

I made **french** the default language because most users are french speaking at first. So **English** became the second language.

I am using **Entity Translation**.

In that website, people who have an account can create content. **But I want the content not to be translatable** apart from menus and some other stuff.

What I want is the content that is writen in french (in the french version) to be displayed only in the french version. And the content that is written in english (in the english version) to be displayed only in English.

I've tried that for days. But all the content is **still showing in both languages**.

**Can you help me please ?**

Answer (score 0):

Entity Translations can be configured so that when it doesn't find content for a field in a language, it uses the content of the default language if any is available. If you're in an English page and a field is missing content, it may pick up the French content.

*This can be disabled* in `/admin/config/regional/entity_translation` by unchecking the "Enable language fallback" checkbox. When disabled, fields that have no content will simply not appear and won't fall back to the default language's content.